# What should i do when i close down one of our counrty from the multiregional and multilanguage site? (SEO Related)

Tags: seo, search-engine, google-search-console

We've a multiregion with multilanguage ecommerce site. Each country site has two or more languages based on the country. For example, Our Brazilian site has 2 languages but our US site has 6 different languages.

We're using subdomain structure for our URLs. Ex: http://us.site.com/en, http://us.site.com/es

Now we're closing down one of our country. Which has the biggest index in our country list. But we don't know what to do before closing it. What do you guys suggest before loose organics or get banned?

Here is our scenarios:

- Redirect all the traffic one of our other country
- Completely close down the site and show "not found" all the indexed pages
- Redirect all the indexed pages to our "Select your country" landing page

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Possibly create a landing page providing options to browse another language page? After all user experience is one of the most important factors. Will redirecting the traffic with a 301 will land users onto a page in a language they might not be able to understand. I would keep some of these points in mind.